# Path stored in plist starting with $HOME does not expand in bash script command

Tags: bash, macos, shell, plist, plistbuddy

I am writing a bash script to automate our build process. I need to store a path in a settings plist file and retrieve it in a shell script, using plistbuddy.

The key below specifies the path where archives will be stored, a folder on the Desktop:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>archives_path</key>
   <string>$HOME/Desktop/Archives/</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

In my shell script I access the key:

```sh
SETTINGS_PATH="path/to/plist/file"

ARCHIVES=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print archives_path" "$SETTINGS_PATH")
#outputs "$HOME/Desktop/Archives/"

mkdir "$ARCHIVES/test/"
#outputs "mkdir: $HOME/Desktop/Archives: No such file or directory"
```

The `ARCHIVES` var is not expanding to `/Users/*username*/Desktop/Archives/`, as I'd expect.

I did a test by creating a var with the same string:

```sh
ARCHIVES="$HOME/Desktop/Archives/" 

echo "$ARCHIVES" 
#expands to "/Users/*username*/Desktop/Archives/"

mkdir "$ARCHIVES/test/"
#creates the 'test' directory
```

As this script will be run under an unknown user account how can I force the $HOME to expand properly.

Comment: Try `mkdir` with option `-p`.

Comment: @Cyrus `mkdir -p $ARCHIVES` creates a folder named `$HOME` on the desktop, containing folders `Desktop/Archives/test/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$ARCHIVE` returned by the `PlistBuddy` contains a literal `$HOME`.

Simple demo:

```
str='$HOME/tmp/somefile'
echo "The HOME isn't expanded: [[$str]]"
```

it prints:

```
The HOME isn't expanded: [[$HOME/tmp/somefile]]
```

You can use `eval` for the expansion like:

```
expanded_str1=$(eval "echo $str")
echo "The HOME is DANGEROUSLY expanded using eval: [[$expanded_str1]]"
```

which prints

```
The HOME is DANGEROUSLY expanded using eval: [[/Users/jm/tmp/somefile]]
```

But using `eval` is dangerous! Evaling any string which isn't absolutely under your control is **really** dangerous.

So, you need manually replace the literal `$HOME` with it's actual *value*. It can be done with many ways, for example:

```
expanded_str2="${str/\$HOME/$HOME}"
# or
expanded_str2=$(echo "$str" | sed "s!\$HOME!$HOME!")
# or
expanded_str2=$(echo "$str" | perl -plE 's/\$(\w+)/$ENV{$1}/g')
# or ... other ways...
```

Using

```
echo "$expanded_str2"
```

prints

```
/Users/jm/tmp/somefile
```